# Wordpress rest api json Does not pull data from non-ssl sites

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, rest, api

```
var apiURL = "https://teknoseyir.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed=true&per_page=4&categories=7&post=";
var apiURL = "http://ravaze.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed=true&per_page=4&categories=7&post=";
```

I can not pull data from my site using http, but it comes from a website with https. I did not do any extra work on Wordpress. I use Wordpress standard rest API. Does not pull data from non-ssl sites

```js
//Developer Site : http://ravaze.com
//Author : EMRE ZAVAR

var posts = null;
var apiURL = "https://teknoseyir.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed=true&per_page=4&categories=7&post=";
var page = 0;


function loadJSON() {
  page = page + 1;
  $("#loadmess").show();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', apiURL + page);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    posts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(posts[0].link);
    makeList(posts);
    page++;
  }
  xhr.send();
}
var primerload = loadJSON(page);
var output = '';

function makeList(posts) {
  for (var i = 0, len = posts.length; i < len; i++) {
    var post_image_full = posts[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.full.source_url;
    var post_image_thumb = posts[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url;
    var post_comment_user_name = posts[i]._embedded['replies'][0][0].author_name;
    var post_comment_content = posts[i]._embedded['replies'][0][0].content.rendered;
    var post_comment_id = posts[i]._embedded['replies'][0][0].id;
    var post_title = posts[i].title.rendered;
    var post_excerpt = posts[i].excerpt.rendered;
    var post_link = posts[i].link;
    var post_cat = posts[i]._embedded['wp:term'][0][0].name;
    var post_cat_link = posts[i]._embedded['wp:term'][0][0].link;
    var post_date = posts[i].date_gmt;

    output += '<div class="col-md-12">\
      <div class="post-grid">\
       <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">\
         <div class="image">\
        <a href="' + post_image_full + '" target="_blank">\
          <img src="' + post_image_thumb + '">\
        </a>\
         </div>\
       </div>\
       <div class="col-md-12 nopadding">\
          <a href="' + post_link + '" target="_blank" >\
         ' + post_title + '\
          </a>\
          <div class="post-excerpt">' + post_excerpt + '</div>\
          <div class="post-cat-name"><a href="' + post_cat_link + '" target="_blank">' + post_cat + '</a></div>\
          <div class="post-date">' + post_date + '</div>\
       </div>\
      </div>\
      <div class="post-comment">\
       <h5>Last Comment Reply</h5>\
       <div class="post-comment-user-name">\
        <a href="' + post_link + '#comment-' + post_comment_id + '" target="_blank">\
         <strong>' + post_comment_user_name + '</strong>\
        </a>\
       </div>\
       <div class="post-comment-content">' + post_comment_content + '</div>\
      </div>\
    </div>';
  }
  output += '';

  $("#loadhere").append(output);
  $("#more").show();
  $("#loadmess").hide();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/tileable_wood_texture.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 200px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

header.header {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.brand {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  display: table;
}

.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}

#loadhere {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#more {
  width: 100%;
}

.cont {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.post-loading-spinner {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.post-grid {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0000001a;
}

.post-grid img {
  width: 235px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.post-grid a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.post-cat-name a {
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.post-excerpt {}

.post-load-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #E91E63;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.post-comment {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}

.post-comment-user-name a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
}

.post-comment-content a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: inherit;
  color: blue;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .post-grid img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .post-cat-name {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    float: none;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .post-excerpt {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .post-grid a {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="brand">Wordpress REST API <code>JSON</code> | <small>Load More Plugin</small></h3>
    <p class="float-left">Sample Site : https://teknoseyir.com</p>
    <p class="float-right">Developer Site : http://ravaze.com</p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="load-wrapper">
    <div id="loadhere">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="post-loading-spinner" id="loadmess">
      <img width="80px" src="https://loading.io/spinners/camera/lg.camera-aperture-ajax-spinner.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
      <div class="post-load-btn" onclick="loadJSON()" id="more" style="display:none;">
        Load More
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your site running under a HTTPS protocol? If so you'll be blocked from loading any content through HTTP. Check the console for errors relating to this

Comment: I do not use ssl on my site.